# QMacStyle that runs on non-Apple operating systems

Tags: windows, macos, qt

I realize that the [QMacStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmacstyle.html) class only runs on Mac OS X.  Are there any 3rd-party styles that could be used to make my app look somewhat similar to that style, but not necessarily identical - and run correctly on other platforms, like MS Windows?

I realize I could write one myself, but I'm looking for something to save a lot of work.